# Matplotlib colours are wrong

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, colors

NOTE: This is now resolved, although I made no changes to my code, but the images are now mysteriously coming out with perfect colour.

I am making plots using Python3 with a Spyder interface. I have looked at the plots both in the Spyder terminal, and in the saved PNGs of the images. Both show that the colours are coming out very badly.

A simple line in the script

```
plt.plot(x1, beta.transpose()[x1], color = 'r', linewidth = 0.2)
```

The red colour is showing as a light pink. When I change 'r' for 'k' to get a black line, it comes as a very light grey. Does anyone know of issues affecting Matplotlib, or Matplotlib used through Spyder, that might account for this?

Example:

[image: Image produced with code as below. A "black" line overlayed on scatter.]

Code:

Data-generating script logit_data.py

```
#Logistic regression data and link function.

import numpy as np

#Define link function here
def g(z):
    g=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    return g

#For producing y data values given true paramters theta and number of covariates
def logit_data(n,p, theta):
    #Define parameters

    #1)Number of covariates
    p_i = p+1  #with intercept
    p_i=np.int(p_i)

    #2) m as correct data type
    n=np.int(n)

    #4)Specify parameter valueas to be estimated
    theta=np.reshape(theta, (p_i,1))

    #5)Define distribution from which covariate values are drawn i.i.d., and initiate data values
    X=np.zeros((n,p_i))
    X[:,0]=1    #intercept
    mean=0
    sigma=1.5

    X[:,1:]=np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(n,p))


    #6)Produce y values treating y as a Bernoulli variable with p=g(X*theta)
    r=np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
    r=np.reshape(r, (len(r),1))
    htrue=g(X.dot(theta))
    y=htrue-r
    y[y>=0]=1
    y[y<0]=0

    return X, y
```

Plotting script:

```
#Script for producing y data from p covariates from a specified distribution, specified beta paraemters,
#and n data samples for logit link function.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from logit_data import logit_data
import pylab
import statsmodels.stats as sms
import statsmodels.api as sma
import csv

def figure2():
    #def MLE_logistic_function():
    #1)Sample and observation numbers
    samples = 30
    observations = 40000

    #2)Number of independent covariates
    p=299

    #3)True beta to be estimated (parameter values)
    nonzerosN=30
    beta1=np.append(np.full((1, nonzerosN),10),np.full((1,nonzerosN),-10), axis=1)
    print(np.shape(beta1))
    beta=np.append(beta1,np.zeros((1,p+1-2*nonzerosN)), axis=1)
    print(np.shape(beta))


    #4)#Initiate arrays to store estimates of beta (and errors) computed at specified sample numbers N
    #Betas=np.zeros((len(npowers),p+1))
    #Errors=np.zeros((len(npowers),p+1))


    #5)Obtain random covariate values from specified distribution, and corresponding y values using true beta
    #plus gaussian noise term.
    X,y = logit_data(observations,p,beta)


    logit = sma.Logit(y,X)
    result = logit.fit()

    print(result.summary())

    MLEcoefficients = result.params
    x1 = np.arange(0, nonzerosN,1)
    x2 = np.arange(nonzerosN, 2*nonzerosN,1)
    x3 = np.arange(2*nonzerosN, p+1,1)
    plt.scatter(index, MLEcoefficients, 0.2)
    plt.plot(x1, beta.transpose()[x1], color = 'black', linewidth = 0.2, alpha=1)
    plt.plot(x2, beta.transpose()[x2], color = 'black', linewidth = 0.2)
    plt.plot(x3, beta.transpose()[x3], color = 'black', linewidth = 0.2)
    plt.xlabel('Index')
    plt.ylabel('Coefficient values (true and fitted)')
    plt.savefig('MMLTfig2_p%s_o%d.png' %(p,observations))
    plt.show()

    return


figure2()
```

Comment: Do you still get the same problem when setting `alpha=1` or increasing your line width?

Comment: Have you tried with 'red' or other colors?

Comment: Somehow you would need to make this reproducible; or if not at least show a screenshot of the output and the complete code that leads to the undesired output.

Comment: @BenT I had indeed tried changing the linewidth. This didn't work. I have now tried setting alpha=1. Doesn't work either.

Comment: @AlessandroPeca I had tried 'red', 'black' as well as single letters, but not other ways of naming the colors.

Comment: Will be adding code and image now.

Comment: What is the variable `index` intended to be? As it stands, we cannot run this code. Upon removal of the offending line, however, I can no longer reproduce your problem - the line colours plot nicely, albeit a little faded due to the reduced `linewidth`.

Comment: @N.Wouda This is very strange. I did not change the code, and yet now that I try it again it is running perfectly, with very clear colours.